# How to make an android tablet to only use 2 specific apps?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

so I am making a Unity app exclusively for Tab A7 Samsung.
I want for the app + a browser to be the only thing the user would be able to see and use.
The app would have a link which would open the browser.
However i have no idea if this is possible or even where would i start.

Basically want to make a kind of child's mode but without all that menus and child games.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [App Pinning](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138?hl=en) on Android, which locks the user in to a particular app. I believe that app can make calls to open other apps like a browser.